# python garbage collector and list

Tags: python, list, garbage-collection

Having issue about garbage collecting in Python 2.7. Why does this code

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __del__(self):
          print self.name,

aa = [A(str(i)) for i in range(10)]

del aa
```

give the output `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` and not `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` or any other permutation.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Where you expecting a specific order?

Comment: It is just a curiosity)

Comment: also PyPy does it like `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` but Jython does it the same way as CPython

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Python list object decreases the reference counts of the items it references in reverse order:

```
static void
list_dealloc(PyListObject *op)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject_GC_UnTrack(op);
    Py_TRASHCAN_SAFE_BEGIN(op)
    if (op->ob_item != NULL) {
        /* Do it backwards, for Christian Tismer.
           There's a simple test case where somehow this reduces
           thrashing when a *very* large list is created and
           immediately deleted. */
        i = Py_SIZE(op);
        while (--i >= 0) {
            Py_XDECREF(op->ob_item[i]);
        }
        PyMem_FREE(op->ob_item);
    }
    if (numfree < PyList_MAXFREELIST && PyList_CheckExact(op))
        free_list[numfree++] = op;
    else
        Py_TYPE(op)->tp_free((PyObject *)op);
    Py_TRASHCAN_SAFE_END(op)
}
```

See that comment; removing references starting from the end apparently reduces thrashing in some cases with large lists.

My guess is that when you create a very large list, the last items are still in the cache and dereferencing those first helps reduce cache churn. Add swapping and starting from the end makes an even bigger difference.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Who is Christian Tismer?))

Comment: Creator of [Stackless Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackless_Python).

Answer (score 3):

Python predominantly relies on reference-counting to manage object lifespans. (I think it uses some kind of mark-and-sweep to handle reference cycles, but don't quote me on that.)

I'd be guessing that, when being destroyed, lists deference their elements in reverse order, hence the behaviour you're seeing.

I don't think that order of destruction of list elements is formally defined, in which case this isn't an "issue" as such.